# 〜しては is this a grammar pattern?

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form, particle-は

I was trying to translate this sentence:

> 僕はアルバイト**しては**レコードばかり買っていたから、一日半働けばLP一枚買えるな、と思って働いていた。

I think I get the overall meaning as: Because I spent all my wages on records I went to work thinking "If I work a day and a half I can buy an LP."

But I'm confused by the アルバイトしては

What's going on with the grammar here?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23584/

Answer (score 10):

I think it might be sense 3 of this [Daijirin definition](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=113492300000&pagenum=1), which defines it as `…するときはいつも…する`, which I think can be defined as "whenever (you) do ..., (you) do ...":

> 僕はアルバイトしてはレコードばかり買っていたから、一日半働けばLP一枚買えるな、と思って働いていた。
>   Whenever I was working part-time, I was solely buying records, so I was working thinking that if I work for a day and a half, I can buy an LP.

For example, from [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&index=12757600&pagenum=1):

> 幼い頃は電車を見ては喜んでいた。
>   When I was young, whenever I saw a train I was delighted.

I think this is distinct from another similar usage of `～ては` (sense 4 at [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=113492300000&pagenum=1)), which is defined as two actions etc which make a pair and are repeated, for example:

> ころんでは起き、ころんでは起きて…
>   (I) alternate between falling down and getting up, falling down and getting up...

**Edit:** Reverted the definition to an earlier version based on suggestions in the comments.

Comment: I think you have the right definition, but the original sentence feels more like this to me: "Each time that A (which would happen repeatedly), then always B would follow", i.e. "I was constantly buying records every time I did a little (part-time) work". See the entry under くり返し [here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/ては) for another example.

Comment: @Hyperworm thanks for the comment - I think you're right, I actually originally wrote "whenever" instead of "alternate between" in the first revision, but I was having trouble finding that usage in Daijisen. It looks to me that Daijisen's sense 3 might include both sense 3+4 from Daijirin.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your earlier revisions :) I felt a little uneasy about posting that comment because I couldn't see a better match in Daijisen than (3), either; luckily I came across that weblio/Kenkyusha entry.

Answer (score 8):

Think of `しては` as a contraction of `して、あとは` as in

> 僕はバイトして、あとはレコードばかり買っていた……

and look over the fact that there are two topic markers `は` in the sentence now.

It then means, that apart from work, all `僕` did was buy records.

This construction can be used with other words as well.

> 僕は食べては、寝ていただけです。
>
> Apart from eating, all I did was sleep.

The point is that the second phrase expresses some restricted action, e.g. using `だけ`, `のみ` or `ばかり` (or `しか+neg.`).