# Explanation/Usage of 瞬きしては

Tags: usage, て-form, particle-は, nominalization

Could it become 瞬【まばた】いている? Why is there 瞬きする instead of 瞬く? And why is there a は at the end?

---

Sentence from the song キラキラ星【ぼし】:

> きらきらひかる　おそらのほしよ
>
> まばたきして**は**　みんなをみてる
>
> きらきらひかる　おそらのほしよ

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/

Answer (score 4):

「[瞬]{まばた}く」 is a fairly "big" word and it would sound too heavy or literary to use in a children's song.  The more common and intuitive word choice for native speakers would be 「瞬き（を）する」 not only for children but also for adults as well.

> 「まばたきし**ては**　みんなをみてる」 is in the structure:
>
> 「A（を）し**ては**B（を）する」= "to do A and B alternately"
>
> = "(The stars) keep blinking and looking at us all."

See Definition #3 here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/152199/m0u/

「は」 is part of the expression and it **cannot** be omitted.