# Unable to understand grammar/meaning here

Tags: grammar, comprehension

Having trouble with the bolded part:

> 沈む太陽が海に溶け、全てを赤く染めあげる一瞬の――儚いけれど鮮烈な一時は、しかしそこで止まっていた。水平線に半ばまで埋もれながら、決して落ちない太陽。**寄せては引き、引いては返すも**、どこか現実味を欠いた潮騒……

What (I think) I understand so far:

> A fleeting but vivid moment when the sinking sun dissolves in the sea, tinting everything red. However, it stops there. This sun, half-buried under the horizon, will certainly not set. **???** Sea roar that is out of touch with reality...

How to translate the bolded part? Is it talking about the tide, so that

> 寄せて**は**引き、引いて**は**返す**も**

Are ほ、も the s.c. 係助詞　and simplifying it into 寄せて引き、引いて返す、どこか現実味を欠いた潮騒 it's basically a long clause ((寄せて引き、引いて返す)、(どこか現実味を欠いた)) of 潮騒?

> sea roar that pulls back, then comes in, then pulls back again [...])? *(again, my English vocabulary is poor so that's probably not the right word for describing tidal movement..*.)

I have only recently read about the s.c. 係助詞 (I don't know if that's the correct notion to use here, even)　and a lot of vocabulary here is unfamiliar to me so I'm looking for help as to whether I understood it correctly.

(btw please correct me if I failed at other parts of translation)

Comment: Related: [Explanation/Usage of 瞬きしては](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23584/7810) and [〜しては is this a grammar pattern?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6669/7810).

Comment: Right, so all the bolded ones are definitely 係助詞? Does the entire clause roughly mean what I wrote (tide pulling back and forth)?

Comment: The last も isn't the part of this construction. も attaches to a verb's dictionary form is a conjunction used in literary language that means "though".

Comment: Ahhh, I see. So *despite* the flow of the waves (still not sure about that part), the sea roar is lacking something that would make it a part of reality? This is starting to make more sense.