# What is this そらしてはなりたい

Tags: て-form, particle-は

https://www.uta-net.com/song/248289/　From this song,

I can't translate " 僕らは目をそらしてはなりたい" and I don't know what's "そらしてはなりたい"

Answer (score 3):

I think you're parsing the clauses incorrectly.

そらして is the te-form of 逸らす (to look away or avoid/change topics)

て-form + は is a conjunction that often means "if/when" but in this case it indicates the repeated actions of 未来の解像度**下げ**, 目を**そらす**, and なりたいものなんて無いと**嘯(うそぶ)いた**.

なりたい is part of the next clause なりたいものなんて無いと嘯(うそぶ)いた日々を. In particular, it modifies もの to mean "something (I/we) want to become".

Comment: `て-form + は is a conjunction that often means "if"` ううん・・　「〘未来の解像度(を)下げ、僕らは目をそらし**ては** 、『なりたいものなんてない』とうそぶいた〙日々」の「～ては」は、if じゃなくて、これ → https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41664/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6672/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23588/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43619/9831

Comment: @Chocolate 指摘してくれてありがとう！

Answer (score -1):

The phrase 僕らは目をそらしてはなりたい contains the following words:

- 僕ら (*bokura*) = this means "we"
- は (*wa*) = [marks the subject 僕ら and 目をそらして](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particles-wa-ga/)
- 目 (*me*) = may mean "vision/sight/gaze"
- を (*o*) = [marks the direct object 目](http://www.punipunijapan.com/grammar-lesson-7-particle-%E3%82%92-o/)
- そらして (*sorashite*) = may mean "to avert"
- なりたい (*naritai*) = may mean "to want"

Hence, the translation of only that particular phrase would be:

> We want to avert our gaze

However, if you meant translating the part of the song where that phrase was taken from, then

> Dreaming　意思逆走
>   四角い空　心の隙間埋めぬ
>   明けぬ夜から抜けよう
>   未来の解像度下げ　**僕らは目をそらしては**
>   **なりたい**ものなんて無いと嘯(うそぶ)いた日々を
>
> Dreaming counter my intentions
>   The sky's four corners, unable to fill my heart's gap
>   Let's escape this endless night
>   The future's resolution dropped, we averted our gaze
>   The days when we bragged about the things we didn't want to be*

For future reference, [this site](http://www.romajidesu.com/translator) may help with translations.

*This might be wrong, so feel free to correct this one.