# Do ては and のは have the same meaning sometimes?

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-は, song-lyrics

I was listening to a song ([ロジックエージェント](https://www.kkbox.com/jp/ja/song/qgNfT2IDoQM5WOQc5WOQc0PL-index.html)) and these lyrics came up:

> 枯れ**ては**戸惑いを募らせて
> 遠く揺らぐ日々を眺めてた

I assume that **ては** means 枯れる**のは**。

Is that correct?

I know **ては** can mean If/When but I don't think this is the case here. Some other parts of the song say 重ね**ては**声, which to me sounds like 重ねるのは声.

Comment: Related, perhaps?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43618/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23584/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41658/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6669/9831

Comment: Maybe for the first part because there are two verbs. "It kept withering and making the disorientation intense" makes sense. But what about the 重ねては声？Do you think it means something like 重ねては声【を上げる】"I keep repeating (something) and raising my voice (and that fails all the time" ????? I really have no idea xD

Comment: 歌詞読みましたけど、意味わかんないですｗ　https://www.kkbox.com/jp/ja/song/qgNfT2IDoQM5WOQc5WOQc0PL-index.html

Comment: 心配しないで。とても詩的で本当に分かりにくいです。それでも、読んでみてくれてありがとう！

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment section, this ては should be part of the [AてはB construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41658/5010). The first line says every time something "withered" or "ran out", this person have grown his/her mental discomfort/confusion.

So what is the subject of 枯れる? The lyrics have nothing to do with growing plants, so I guess the subject of 枯れる is his/her memory or passion. 枯れる can be used with words like 涙, 思い and 情熱 as the subject. The lyrics of this song are fairly vague, but I can say this person is gradually losing past memories with 君.

Comment: Thank you! I confirmed with a native and she said it really implies a 「声を出す/声をあげる」。as well as the ては。。。て construction.