# "Te-form" versus "masu-stem + して" (消しているうちに versus 消ししているうちに)

Tags: grammar, nuances, て-form, particle-は

Is there any difference between 消して and 消しして in the following sentences?

For example,

> A: 手紙を書いては消し、書いては**消しして**いるうちに、朝になってしまった。
>
> B: 手紙を書いては消し、書いては**消して**いるうちに、朝になってしまった。

Comment: This question is not specific to the verb 消す; I edited the title hoping this question generally covers this pattern for future readers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`A (te-form) + は + B (masu-form)` is a common pattern that describes someone repeatedly/habitually does B right after A as a paired action. See: [〜しては is this a grammar pattern?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6669/5010) This set is often repeated for emphasis: `A ては B、A ては B`.

- 幼い頃、よく泣いては母親を困らせていた。
  When I was young I *always* cried and annoyed my mother.

Interestingly, `AてはB` as a whole sometimes behaves like a long noun phrase. B can be a te-form, too:

- 食【く】っては寝【ね】**の**生活をする
  食っては寝て**の**生活をする
  to live idly (do nothing but eating and sleeping)
- 食っちゃ寝、食っちゃ寝**の**生活をする (emphasized)
- 作っては壊し(て)**の**連続で、まったく完成しない。
- 家に帰っては呼び出され(て)**で**、休む暇がない。
  Because I am called right after returning home many times, I have no time to rest.
- 映画を見てはブログに感想を書き、**を**3年続けました。

And it can even take another する as if `AてはB` were a long suru-verb!

- 冬休みの間は、食っちゃ寝、食っちゃ寝していました。
- 稼いでは使い、稼いでは使いしていたら、お金は貯まらないよ。

Of course you cannot usually say 寝する nor 使いする.

I feel `AてはB` tends to be treated like a noun especially when two verbs are short and commonly paired; e.g., 食っては寝, 書いては消し, 打っては走り, 作っては壊し, [ちぎっては投げ](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8E%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E6%8A%95%E3%81%92%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8E%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E6%8A%95%E3%81%92%E3%81%AE).

Answer (score 4):

Their meaning are the same but the structure of them are a bit different.

If を add the sentence A, it is easy to understand like 手紙を書いては消し、書いては消しをしているうちに.That is to say, I am doing the action of 書いては消し,書いては消し(write and erase).

書いては消している is progressive form of 書いては消す.