# What does ては mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-は

> 寝太郎{ねたろう}はのんきに空{そら}をながめ**ては**暮{く}らしておりました。

My translation: Netarou was living by heedlessly looking the sky.

What does ては mean in this sentence?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41658/5010 You've asked about this before :) But I feel this sentence is a bit unnatural because 暮らす is not a short action...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「Verb A in **て/で**-form + **は** + Verb B」

means:

> "to do A and B repeatedly as in a pair"

So, your translation looks good.

By far the most common and "famous" phrase using this structure would be 「食{く}っちゃ寝{ね}」, which is the colloquial pronunciation of 「食っては寝(て or る)」. That means "someone just eats and sleeps all day".

[image]

Comment: Does this 「食っちゃ寝」expression sound slightly 'rough'?

Comment: Just a lttle bit, maybe, but not so much at all.  It is in such wide use and it kinda sounds "lively" if anything.  It says a lot in just three syllables.