# ては's role in this 「追いかけては来ないでしょう」

Tags: て-form

So I've read this article about 「ては」 ["Te-form" versus "masu-stem + して" (消しているうちに versus 消ししているうちに)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41658/te-form-versus-masu-stem-%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-%E6%B6%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB-versus-%E6%B6%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB/41664#41664)

then I understand that there are 2 meanings. First is "Repeated/Habitual action"

and the next one is "AてはB tends to be treated like a noun especially when two verbs are short and commonly paired"

Therefore I think "追いかけては" in「追いかけては来ないでしょう」acts as a noun

Is it right. Is this　"追いかけては" in this sentence same feeling as "追いかけるのは" ?

Answer (score 6):

No, in this example 追いかけては is not functioning as a noun, and in fact I don't think this is an example of ては as it's explained in the article you linked to at all. I believe this is an instance in which は has simply been inserted to add emphasis:

> 追いかけてこないでしょう
>
> "They probably won't chase us," "He probably won't come after us," etc.

becomes

> 追いかけて**は**こないでしょう
>
> "They probably won't *chase* us," "He probably won't *come after* us," etc.

In other words, I think this is the usage of は that's covered by the following part of the definition of the particle は in 大辞林 (note especially the third and fourth usage examples):

> ④叙述を強める。[…]
>
> ㋑〔動詞・形容詞の連用形、および助詞「てで」に付いて〕一続きの叙述の一部分を強調する。「絶対に行き━しない」「なるほど美しく━ある」「少なくともわかって━いる」「まだ書いて━いない」「真実で━ない

Answer (score 0):

I think it's used as meaning 1 in [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF) to indicate a hypothetical.

> ①  ある事柄が実現した場合を仮定して、条件として示す。望ましくない事柄についていうことが多い。もし…したら。
>   「計画が敵に知られ－、せっかくの苦心も水の泡だ」 「この辺は危険ですから、泳いではいけません」

That is to say 追いかけ**ては**来ないでしょう could be replaced with **もし**追いかけ**たら**来ないでしょう