# Why is there a する used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 士道は身体中が上げる悲鳴を無視しながら全身に力を込め、<暴虐公>を弾くと、そのまま<鏖殺公>を振り上げる。
>
> 無論、そんな一撃が天香に通用するとは思っていない。容易く受け止められるか、避けられるか**する**のがオチだろう。

Why is there a する used in this sentence? Is it necessary? It doesn’t seem to add any meaning to the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like ～たり～たり and [～ては～](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41664/5010), ～か～か works both as a long noun and as a long suru-verb.

- 食べたり飲んだりするのを繰り返す。
- 食べたり飲んだりを繰り返す。
- 寝るか勉強するかしろ。
- 寝るか勉強するか(を)選べ。
- 生きるか死ぬかの勝負だ。

So the following sentences are all valid and mean the same thing:

- 容易く受け止められるか、避けられるかするのがオチだろう。
- 容易く受け止められるか、避けられるかがオチだろう。
- 容易く受け止められるか、避けられるのがオチだろう。

Unlike ～たり～たり, it's usually fine to drop the second か, as in the third example. Still, keeping the two か's and treating them as a long suru-verb is the most explicit and "canonical" way. This する is not strictly necessary, but it's better to keep it at least in very formal sentences.

Comment: 「容易く受け止められるか、避けられるかがオチだろう。」はどうしてもeither...orではなくwhetherに聞こえてしまうので個人的には容認度低いですね…