# Role of は when following phrases ending in particles

Tags: particles, particle-は, linguistics

I have read several linguistic accounts of the particle は that claim it has two fundamental uses:

1. To indicate the theme/topic of the discourse (assuming that the speaker can take for granted that the audience understands what he is specifically referring to , ie, the theme is anaphoric or generic).
2. To indicate contrast.

None of these accounts ever discuss what happens when you have particle + は situations. For example, situations like:

1. Noun + で + は
2. Sentence + まで + は
3. Sentence + て + は

My question is, in situations like those above (phrase + particle + は), can は take the thematic meaning or is it restricted to the contrastive meaning? Or perhaps its meaning is altogether different and particle combinations like では, までは, ては, and には should be considered separate entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in situations like those above (phrase + particle + は), can は take the thematic meaning or is it restricted to the contrastive meaning?

Yes, the two fundamental meanings are preserved even when は is preceded by で, から, etc. But note that the border between thematic-は and contrastive-は is sometimes blurry.

Thematic は:

- 東京**では**雪が降っています。
- この店**には**寿司があります。
- ここ**からは**道が狭くなります。
- 駅**までは**10分です。
- 彼**とは**友達です。

Contrastive は:

- 硬いですが、ナイフ**では**切れます。<sup>1</sup>
- 彼**には**できなくても私**には**できます。
- 目的地はこの場所**からは**見えない山です。<sup>2</sup>
- 夜**までは**待ちましょう。<sup>1</sup>
- AはB**とは**違う概念です。<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1: Some contrastive-は can be translated as "at least".

2: は in a relative clause is usually contrastive.</sup>

And some combinations have special meanings:

- ラーメンがこんなにおいしい**とは**！
- スズメ**とは**鳥の一種です。

The same is true when から/まで takes a clause:

- (thematic) この橋を越えて**からは**東京です。
- (contrastive) 失敗して**からは**気付ける教訓がある。

て is not a case particle but a special auxiliary that follows a verb (not a noun). ては/では is normally contrastive, but it has special functions like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41658/5010).

- 見**ては**いましたが触っ**ては**いません。
- 彼はもう生き**ては**いないだろう。