# Why does the composer of キティ use を after a verb's て-form and before a suru verb (輪廻)

Tags: grammar, meaning, song-lyrics, multiple-readings

There's a line in the song キティ saying 日月さえも孤独な天下で絡まって解いてを輪廻する愚者の群れ
At first I assumed it was a form of keigo because  を is sometimes used as お, or in archaic Japanese, at least I believe, because when you search verbs with お in them some dictionaries replace お with を. However, it seems it is not so because nouns that would be paired with する to make a verb are paired with です, になる or polite suru verbs like いたす and なさる. In addition. the kanji was found on プロセカ's 2D mv, despite it not being released to the official youtube channel, from what I heard, it was released to the JP ver. of the game. Please explain this use of を, or お for me
Edit: Let me check if it says は or を after 解いて

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Te-form" versus "masu-stem + して" (消しているうちに versus 消ししているうちに)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41658/te-form-versus-masu-stem-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-%e6%b6%88%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%ab-versus-%e6%b6%88%e3%81%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%ab)

Comment: Actually i searched up te wo and the answer for that does help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for helping, I didn't think it helped until i searched てを on this site

Comment: More clarification: how does を work witg 輪廻 if 輪廻 is an intransitive verb

Comment: They are using it transitively like they would 繰り返す.

Comment: so to repeat untangle and entangle?

Comment: I don't understand the lyric with that information

Comment: How can you use 輪廻 as a transitive verb and it makes sense?