# 輪廻's meanings (cycle) where does it come from?

Tags: etymology, particle-を, definitions, transitivity

Last weekish or so I made a question about てを verb, and a person told me it was a duplicate question, and that 輪廻 in the case my question was being asked was transitive. So I searched on wiktionary and found a definition for it that meant cycle. But when I searched 輪廻とは, I didn't find any dictionaries that supported that definition on the front page. I know it can mean attachment, reincarnation or any other thing on that list but I am not finding the cycle meaning. Does 輪廻 have a cycle meaning?

Comment: Context: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99525/why-does-the-composer-of-%e3%82%ad%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3-use-%e3%82%92-after-a-verbs-%e3%81%a6-form-and-before-a-suru-verb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of （を）輪廻する as a transitive verb to mean 'repeat something/some action' seems like poetic license considering [the use mentioned is from a song](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99525/why-does-the-composer-of-%e3%82%ad%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3-use-%e3%82%92-after-a-verbs-%e3%81%a6-form-and-before-a-suru-verb). In other words, it's a stretch of the word's current usage, which is possible in a song but not much elsewhere. Nobody says ロボットが部屋の掃除を輪廻している in modern Japanese with a straight face.

The concept of 輪廻 does involve cyclicity, though. [The word 輪廻 is originally the Chinese translation of saṃsāra](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%BC%AA%E5%BB%BB-150461). "Popularly, it is the cycle of death and rebirth" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra . It is usually not employed outside of the context of Buddhism and Indian religions.